# Using a return keyword with no return value?

Tags: php

I have been noticing in some PHP design patterns, some authors who write code examples, have  return inside the method but it doesn't specify return value .
 It just says "return"

Can some one please explain me what is the purpose of doing that? Below is an example

Thank you!

```
function addListItem(ListItem $listItem){
    if(in_array($listItem, $this->listitems, true)){
        return;
    }
    $this->listitems[] = $listItem;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done for side-effects (IO, altering globals, or the arguments passed by reference, or an object property, like in your example -- `$this->listitems[] = $listItem;`), or to indicate it's impossible to yield a valid result.

```
return;
```

is equivalent to

```
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement will *stop* the function immediately after it has been called. Because we do not want any value to be returned like integers, string or booleans, we just stop it so the code will not continue.

This can also be compared to `break` in a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: I had a feeling that is what it was used for , but just wanted t double check. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, you may hit an `if` statement that makes the rest of the code in the method unnecessary.

For example:

```
if(user->log_in == "")
{
    show_error_msg();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "technically more correct" way of writing such code is:

```
if( !in_array($listItem, $this->listitems, true)) {
    $this->listitems[] = $listItem;
}
```

However, sometimes you may have more complex testing, and proceeding in this manner may result in a single `if` block spanning several lines with many `&&`s, or nested `if` statements that fall off the edge of your screen.

Therefore, it is common to see the pattern of your code, namely "check failure conditions and exit the current block if necessary". This means you can have as few or as many conditions as you want, each with their own failure conditions, and if the code manages to reach the end of it then you're good to go.

In some cases, error handling is useful. Something like:

```
try {
    if( failure condition 1) throw new Exception("Error message 1");
    if( failure condition 2) throw new Exception("Error message 2");
    // ...
    do something here;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    // report error here
}
```